# Python memory error for integer and math

Tags: python, memory, integer

When I run my code below I get Memory Error

```
import math
X = 600851475143
halfX = math.trunc(int(X / 2))
countFactors = 0
for i in range(halfX):
    if i >0 and X % i:
        countFactors += 1
print countFactors
```

I understand because of math calcs here but I do not know how to correct it.

Comment: Are you using python 2.x or 3.x?  (`range` will try to create a very large list in your example if you're using 2.x)

Comment: You should use `xrange()` instead of `range()` .

Comment: Perfect. Thank you !

Comment: Incidentally, `X % i` is not the same thing as "X is divisible by i". When X is divisible by i, `X % i` evaluates to zero.

Comment: As a way to count factors that is incredibly inefficient. Why not factor `X` into primes and determine the multiplicities of the prime factors? The result would be 1 less that the product of (m+1) where m ranges over the multiplicities of the primes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess you're using Python 2.7 (or 2.x, at any rate).

If that's the case, you should use `xrange` instead of `range`.

In python 3.x, `range` creates an iterator that only uses a few bytes of memory regardless of how large it is.  In python 2.x, `range` always creates a list containing numbers counting up (or down) over the specified range.  Calling `range(some_large_number)` can cause you to run out of memory in 2.x.

Therefore, Python 2.x has `xrange` which creates an iterator identical to `range` in 3.x.

Also, you can simplify your math somewhat. For example:

```
x = 600851475143
half_x = x // 2

count_factors = 0
for i in xrange(half_x):
    if i > 0 and x % i == 0:
        count_factors += 1

print count_factors
```

However, there are much more efficient ways to do this.

As a simple example, if the number is divisible by two, you can iterative over every other number, cutting the number of tests in half.  Similarly, if it's divisible by 3, 5, etc.

I'll leave it to you to figure out the generalization.  It's a fun problem :)